# Не работают зависимости при переходе на .Net core 5

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-5

Не работают зависимости при переходе на .Net core 5. Даже System и тд. .Net Core 5 стоит, проверял в командной строке. Ставил через установщик, может что-то не до конца поставил. Пробовал переустанавливать - тоже самое. runtime и sdk ставил. Комп перезагружал.

upd:
screenshot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переход с чего?

Comment: Все новые проекты с такой ошибкой. До этого стоял 3.1.  Все новые созданные проекты работают только на 3.1.

Comment: может поможет https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/efa3cf/creating-Asp-Net-5-web-application-with-visual-studio-code253/

Comment: "может что-то не до конца поставил" ну ещё раз поставьте. А ещё подробнее опишите как и что не работает. Visual Studio какая версия?

Comment: 2019. Обновлял где-то месяца 3 назад. Щас приложу скриншот с проблемой.

Comment: Нажмите сверху "Справка" - "О программе" и посмотрите конкретно какая там версия студии. .NET 5 доступен только в студии версии `16.8.0` и выше. Также у вас должен быть установлен SDK пакет для .NET 5.